# Problems with fetching div's ID

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a problem with getting the div's ID from my application.
I have a JSP file, which generates a HTML. I want to fetch div ID, but every time my alert is that id name is undefined.

In my JS file there is a simple function:

```
function myFunction(){
  alert(this.id);
}
```

Divs IDs are generated dynamically. In my JSP file I have a simple onclick connection.

What's the reason of not having an ID as a result of the click?

Comment: How you are calling the function?

Comment: onclick="myFunction()" in my DIV header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refer to [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object which does not have property named *id*, thus you get `undefined`. Pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function:

**Demo:**

```js
function myFunction(el){
  //console.log(this.constructor.name); //Window
  alert(el.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" onclick="myFunction(this)">Test Container</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the object being passed to the function.

```
<div id="test" onclick="myFunction(this)">Test Container</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(arg){
              alert(arg.id);
            }
</script>
```